# Page won't redirect if user is not logged in

Tags: php, session, mysqli, authentication

> usercheck.php

```
// Start a session.
session_start();

// Check the database for the user.
$user_check = $_SESSION['user_username'];
$ses_sql    = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user_username FROM users WHERE user_username='$user_check' ");
$row        = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$login_user = $row['user_username'];

// If the check fails, redirect to the login page.
if(!isset($user_check)) {
    header("Location: /index.php");
}
```

I have a file indcluded on every page that is supposed to check to see if the user is logged in. If they are, it shows the page. If not, it redirects back to the index.

The problem is that it's **not** redirecting and I cant quite figure out why. I can easily type the URL of the page I want to go to and bypass the login completely even with this file successfully included.

Am I doing something wrong or outdated?

> **Edit:** Example of a page containing the file.

```
<?php
    $pageTitle = 'Dashboard';
    $pageClass = 'dashboard';
    include_once('./assets/template/template.php');

    // Start the page content.
    function getPageContent() { 

        global $mysqli;

        // Connect to database.
        include_once('./assets/include/db-connect.php');

        // Check the database for the user.
        include_once('./assets/include/db-user-check.php');

        ?>

        ... some html ...

        <?

        // Close the database connection.
        $db->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: And `$_SESSION['user_username']` is always defined?

Comment: Yes, `$_SESSION['user_username'] = $_POST['user_username'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if(!isset($user_check)) {` to `if(!isset($login_user)) {`. It could be that the value of `$_SESSION['user_username']` isn't correct. If that isn't the case, try `var_dump($_SESSION); exit();` inside your if statement and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: The `$login_user` didn't do anything different. I did the `var_dump` and it gave me `array(1) { ["user_username"]=> string(9) "pruoccojr" }`.

Comment: If you reached the 'var_dump' statement than you can conclude that the issue lies within how you are redirecting and not the check itself. 'header("Location: /index.php");' looks okay, but are you sure that you aren't receiving any PHP errors? You may need to check your error logs. You can't modify the headers after content is sent so my first guess would be that you are accidentally sending some content. [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)